# Libraries, functions, and tools that help with secure C/C++ programming on Linux

Tags: linux, programming

When writing software in a language such as C/C++, what tools/libraries/functions are available to help make the program more secure from exploitation on Linux?

For example: one can use `chroot()` and `setuid()` to constrain a process and drop privileges respectively. There are many other tools/libraries such as:

- **Libraries**: Libseccomp, Libsafe, Libcap2, Libfuzzer
- **OS Controls**: Linux Namespaces, `chroot`, `setuid`
- **Tools**: Using stack canaries in GCC (`-fstack-protector`)

I realize that there are more tools such as SELinux, GrSecurity and Virtualization, but I am looking more for things that a *programmer* is responsible for doing vs. a sys-admin.

Thanks!

Comment: this is really broad - the list of things could be endless - can you narrow your scope at all?